# Rails + AJAX is returning more HTML than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm new to Rails and appreciate any insight! Updating Rails' or Ruby's version is not an option, I am being required to use my client's current version.

Ruby version: 1.9.3-p194, Rails version: 3.2.18

I'm loading in dynamic HTML content through a JavaScript/jQuery Ajax call. Everything works fine when I make the Ajax call from inside of app/assets/javascripts/application.js. Here's the call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/search/login',
        cache: true,
        success: function(html){
            console.log('SUCCESS: ', html);
        }
    });
```

The response variable called *html* contains all the HTML inside of /search/login.html.erb

However, if I move that exact call to another JavaScript file such as app/assets/javascripts/search/jh.js, everything seems to work fine except the HTML that's returned is a *LOT* more than expected. It actually contains the entire HTML DOM tree, from `<DOCTYPE>` to `</html>` in addition to the content from /search/login.html.erb.

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: have you tried `layout: false` in your render statement in the controller? Seems more like a Controller issue than a jQuery issue.

Comment: Can you post both methods' code: `login` and `jh` from search controller?

Comment: @engineersmnky you nailed it! Thank you so much. If you leave your comment as an answer I will select it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that you do not want to render the layout for this type of ajax call otherwise Rails will treat it as a standard view request inclusive of the application or template layout. To do this you just need to add the following to the render action in the Controller

```
 render layout: false
```

This tell Rails to just process the html.erb file without the application layout or other template specified for this Controller.